# Creating a javascript notification plugin: How to align absolutely positioned divs on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a notification plugin. I have following code

**javascript**

```
function notification () {

    var wrapper = document.createElement('div'),
        docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    wrapper.textContent = 'Default text';

    wrapper.classList.add('notif');

    docFrag.appendChild(wrapper);


    document.body.appendChild(docFrag);

    var a = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).height;

  wrapper.classList.add('animated');


}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #e2e2e2;
}
.notif {
  position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.animated {
      opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

When the `notification ()` is called a new notification should be added. When a new notification is being added if already a notification is existing, the existing notification should be animated and pushed down and the new notification should position on top of it. And the notification should be `absolutely` positioned. But with my code the divs stack upon each other and those do not flow from top to bottom. How can i achieve this.

Here is the working with code:  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/or2guu05/)** Please run `notification()`  to see the issue.

here is what i want to develop: **[Required look](https://jsfiddle.net/oxejL2bs/)**

**EDIT**

It has to be absolutely , or fixed positioned because the notification should not affect the other content of the webpage.

Comment: Please excuse me for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The notifications seem to stack on top of one another because you assigned their position as absolute. If you set their display attribute to block and do not set their position attribute to absolute, you won't have to worry about this. You can still set the position attribute of the container of these notifications to absolute if you wish to free it from positioning relative to the rest of the DOM.
2. The appendChild() method inserts the element inside the container-element at the end. Try using `docFrag.insertBefore(wrapper, docFrag.firstChild);`.

Comment: There is no such thing as `position: block`. You probably meant something else.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Thank you for pointing out the error. I meant setting the display attribute to block.

Comment: Thanks. I know this happens because of absolute positioning. But that is a requirement. Please see the edit section of my question. Please excuse my english :)

Comment: @Bhuthaya I understand what you are trying to make. Try setting the position of the container to absolute. That way, you can position the element on a nav-bar or anywhere else without disrupting the rest of the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work because absolutley positioned elements stay in the specified place. What you could do instead is absolutley position the container and append your divs inside that. Divs as block elements will naturally push themselves down.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I already knew that. My question is that how to create a notification like what i have mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they're stack on top of eachother is because they're absolutely positioned. You can use the method [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) to fix your issue.

**Summary of the article:**

When positioning elements absolutely their bounding box is by default the `body`.
However, when you add the absolutely positioned element to a relatively positioned element, the bounding box of the absolutely positioned element will change to the relatively positioned elements space.

The HTML would look something like:

```
<relative-element>
    <absolute-element>
        <!-- Content -->
    </absolute-element>
</relative-element>
```

With CSS that would look something like:

```
relative-element {
    position: relative;
}

absolute-element {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Applying the article to your problem**

Create a container and position it relatively.
Add another container to it and position it absolutely. (This will hold your notifications)
Add children to the last container and they will stack like you want them to.

Comment: This link is good, but please include the information on SO when possible in case the website you linked doesn't exist anymore in the future.

Comment: It isn't actually I think, since the dialogue of the post relies on the images being there. I could however summarize the contents of the post?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a crazy way:

- add a wrapper for notification block (notif-wrapper);
- each new block (also wrapped with notif-wrapper) insert before all blocks into deepest notification wrapper `$newNotifWrapper.insertBefore(jQuery('.nofit-wrapper .notif').last())` and add css `.notif .notif {top: 0; left: 0;}`
- each new notif-wrapper after displaying should animate its height

But obviously, simplier and better way is create a single wrapper for all your notifications, add it once on first notification coming and insert all those new notifications before first child of this wrapper, animating their height, ofcourse.